# How to use PKCanvasView functionality without PKToolPicker?

Tags: swift, swiftui, pkcanvasview, pktoolpicker

I want to use **PKCanvasView** functionality without **PKToolPicker**.
As soon as I set **PKToolPicker** visibility to false **PKCanvasView** draws noting.

What is the way to hide **PKToolPicker** and use **PKCanvasView**?

Here is the code which I am using:

```
struct DrawingView: View {
    private var canvasView = PKCanvasView()

    var body: some View {
        MyCanvas(canvasView: canvasView)
    }
}

struct MyCanvas: UIViewRepresentable {
    var canvasView: PKCanvasView
    let picker = PKToolPicker.init()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
        self.canvasView.tool = PKInkingTool(.marker, color: .black, width: 1)
        self.canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()
        return canvasView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {
        picker.addObserver(canvasView)
        picker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: uiView)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must specify the drawing policy if you do not use a `PKToolPicker`.

Something like this:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
    self.canvasView.tool = PKInkingTool(.marker, color: .black, width: 1)
    self.canvasView.drawingPolicy = .anyInput // Specify the drawing policy
    self.canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()
    return canvasView
}
```